# Excel Open in Protected View and Can't Run VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` for some VBA code in order to run those code when I open the workbook. I try it on my laptop, it works fine but when I send the file to my colleague the file, it opens in protected view, and then when clicking the enable editing, it got `Error code 1004: Method ‘Sheets’ of Object ‘_Global’ Failed`. Try to surf the internet, it said that because the file opens on protected view so the VBA won't run.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "file opens on **projected** view"? Do you want saying "protected"? Please, edit your question and show us the code line raising the error. Otherwise, is difficult to suggest solutions or explain the error. It may be almost anything... If the code open, let as say, the active workbook and it does not have a specific sheet you try setting, such an error appears.

Comment: @FaneDuru I look up on the internet and found on https://www.vishalon.net/blog/resolved-method-sheets-of-object-_global-failed

it said that looks like my file was detected from the internet in my colleague's laptop so Excel protect it in order to save the user from opening a threat file.
any idea to make the file open not in protected view?

Comment: my bad should be protected, not projected

Comment: In order to avoid opening in protected view, there are some things to be done, according to the workbook provenience and its folder location. If the workbook is downloaded from the net or received by mail, after saving it, right click its icon, choose `Properties`, check the bottom check box "Unblock" and press "OK". Then, place the folder in Excel `Trusted Locations`. `Options` - `Trust Center` - `Trust Center Settings...` - `Trusted Locations`, press `Add  new location...` find the folder in the browse window and press 'OK'. I have somewhere a macro doing that automatically looks complicated

Comment: But the raised error nothing to do with the protected view case...